# How can I tell if my CSS style changes will affect other pages?

Tags: css

I lead a team of junior developers that would change CSS styles without the realization that their change would affect the other pages of our website as well.

Is there an extension or technique that I can use to let them know if they change this class color, ALL these pages (we have over 100 pages) with the same class would be affected as well?

Comment: I know this might sound stupid, but they should know that classes are global. A quick search in any good IDE will tell them the files those are used in and if they don't want other files to change they have to be more specific. Telling them that **should** be enough.

Comment: Your team should already know this if they are working on a production code, or they *should* know what css files they are editing and how it applies in scope to the site.

Comment: @SourceOverflow that is true.  I plan on teaching them CSS-specificity calculations

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately is not that easy. It all depends on how well your css is structured and maintained.

There are many css guidelines that can help you to solve this problem.

What you can do is use namespaces. It suggest that you use different individual namespaces to help you with css scaling.

Some of namespaces are:

**o-:** Signify that something is an Object, and that it may be used in any number of unrelated contexts to the one you can currently see it in. Making modifications to these types of class could potentially have knock-on effects in a lot of other unrelated places. Tread carefully.

**c-:** Signify that something is a Component. This is a concrete, implementation-specific piece of UI. All of the changes you make to its styles should be detectable in the context you’re currently looking at. Modifying these styles should be safe and have no side effects.

**u-:** Signify that this class is a Utility class. It has a very specific role (often providing only one declaration) and should not be bound onto or changed. It can be reused and is not tied to any specific piece of UI. You will probably recognise this namespace from libraries and methodologies like SUIT.

**t-:** Signify that a class is responsible for adding a Theme to a view. It lets us know that UI Components’ current cosmetic appearance may be due to the presence of a theme.

**s-:** Signify that a class creates a new styling context or Scope. Similar to a Theme, but not necessarily cosmetic, these should be used sparingly—they can be open to abuse and lead to poor CSS if not used wisely.

**is-, has-:** Signify that the piece of UI in question is currently styled a certain way because of a state or condition. This stateful namespace is gorgeous, and comes from SMACSS. It tells us that the DOM currently has a temporary, optional, or short-lived style applied to it due to a certain state being invoked.

**_:** Signify that this class is the worst of the worst—a hack! Sometimes, although incredibly rarely, we need to add a class in our markup in order to force something to work. If we do this, we need to let others know that this class is less than ideal, and hopefully temporary (i.e. do not bind onto this).

**js-:** Signify that this piece of the DOM has some behaviour acting upon it, and that JavaScript binds onto it to provide that behaviour. If you’re not a developer working with JavaScript, leave these well alone.

**qa-:** Signify that a QA or Test Engineering team is running an automated UI test which needs to find or bind onto these parts of the DOM. Like the JavaScript namespace, this basically just reserves hooks in the DOM for non-CSS purposes.

For more read here:

https://csswizardry.com/2015/03/more-transparent-ui-code-with-namespaces/

Comment: That is actually a really good idea. +1 Just two things, I'd like to add: 1) those are **not** real namespaces, but prefixes. The nearest thing to a namespace would be something like a `sidebar-container` and later I use e.g. `.sidebar-container .button` to reference the buttons in that container. 2) Unless you have to look out for performance, especially with jQuery, you should think about using attributes instead of classes with `is-, has-` prefixes for states, as that does make a cleaner distinction between style and function and is even clearer when using them.

Answer (score 0):

Get license for [Applitool](https://applitools.com/) or similar software in your company and through this you can create a visual baseline for all those pages and Applitool app will throw an error if that page changes visually.

If the change is acceptable for you then you can go ahead and accept the changes to be your new baseline if not then you need to revisit the issue.

Comment: Sure np I understand the reason plus in a corporate environment a reason why this is so difficult is cause resources might change and unless they have prior knowledge of how those changes impact they would have no idea neither would you. So automated visual testing is the way to go my friend.